# BIRT export of PDF report displays blank values for 4-byte UTF8 characters

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, birt

I am using BIRT version 3.7.1. When I display a table with values from the database using the default PDF emitter, the 4-byte UTF8 characters are displayed as blank. Does anyone know if this is a known issue in BIRT 3.7.1 or is there a config that I could change to enable these characters to be written in the PDF?

Comment: Are the characters displaying in the query preview and/or in other formats (i.e. Excel or text)?

Comment: The 4-byte UTF-8 characters are displaying in HTML format (using the same emitter) and XLS format using Tribix birt emitter (org.uguess.birt.report.engine.emitter.xls)

Answer (score 0):

try with this if you want to deploy on utf-8

change the java options if you has tomcat

`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

and change the server.xml in tag connector add this

`URIEncoding="UTF-8"`